# Migration tool for ANTLR grammar

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr4

Suppose I have a following simple grammar (query DSL):

```
grammar TestGrammar;

term : textTerm ;

textTerm : 'Text' '(' T_VALUE '=' STRING+ ')' ;

T_VALUE : 'value' ;
STRING : '"' .+? '"' ;

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Then at some point I decide that text term format needs to be changed, for example:

```
Text(value = "123") -> MyText(val = "123")
```

How should I approach migrating existing data that users have generated with previous version of grammar?

Comment: For simple changes like these, `TokenStreamRewriter` is exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks, @LucasTrzesniewski. I finally managed to try this and it seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Assumption

Let's make one simplification of your grammar by introducing token `TEXT` for `'Text'` string.

```antlr
grammar TestGrammar;

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);  // preserve the whitespaces characters!
T_VALUE : 'value';
STRING : '"' .+? '"';
TEXT : 'Text';

term
    : textTerm;
textTerm
    : TEXT '(' T_VALUE '=' STRING+ ')';
```

#### Solution

Now we will utilize the AST listener built by ANTLRv4 tool. This allows us to traverse AST and perform token replacement with `TokenStreamRewriter` class already mentioned by *Lucas Trzesniewski* in comments.

```java
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.TokenStreamRewriter;

public class MigrationTask extends TestGrammarBaseListener {
    private TokenStreamRewriter rewriter;

    public MigrationTask(CommonTokenStream stream) {
        this.rewriter = new TokenStreamRewriter(stream);
    }

    @Override
    public void enterTextTerm(TestGrammarParser.TextTermContext ctx) {
        rewriter.replace(ctx.TEXT().getSymbol(), "MyText");
        rewriter.replace(ctx.T_VALUE().getSymbol(), "val");
    }

    public String getMigrationResult() {
        return rewriter.getText();
    }
}
```

So, we substitute given token with its replacement whenever we encounter the token during the traversal of AST.

#### Usage

Now we can execute `MigrationTask` on given `ParseTree` and retrive the migration result:

```java
(...)
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
TestGrammarParser parser = new TestGrammarParser(tokens);
ParseTree tree = parser.term();
ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
MigrationTask migrationTask = new MigrationTask(tokens);
walker.walk(migrationTask, tree);
String result = migrationTask.getMigrationResult(); // Here we retrive migration result !
(...)
```

Comment: Thank you, it does the work! In order to preserve spaces, I only had to make one change: use `channel(HIDDEN)` instead of `skip` for whitespaces.

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov : you are welcome ! Yes, the `channel(HIDDEN)`, thank you. I will use this to simplify the answer for the posterity.