# ANTLR4 extraneous input

Tags: antlr4

I have a problem with my ANTLR4. I'm trying to print AST from python 3 code but there are some errors and I don't know how to fix them.

I wrote simple code for test:

```
a=(1,2,3)
print(a)
```

I ran the program but this errors appeared:

```
line 1:1 extraneous input '=' expecting {<EOF>, '.', '*', '(', '**', '[', '|', '^', '&', '<<', '>>', '+', '-', '/', '%', '//', '@'}
line 2:0 extraneous input '\n' expecting {<EOF>, '.', '*', '(', '**', '[', '|', '^', '&', '<<', '>>', '+', '-', '/', '%', '//', '@'}
line 3:0 extraneous input '\n' expecting {<EOF>, '.', '*', '(', '**', '[', '|', '^', '&', '<<', '>>', '+', '-', '/', '%', '//', '@'}
```

My main class :

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;
import org.antlr.v4.*;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRFileStream("/home/grzegorz/Desktop/Python3/input.txt");
            Python3Lexer lexer = new Python3Lexer(input);
            CommonTokenStream token = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
            Python3Parser parser = new Python3Parser(token);
            ParseTree parseTree = parser.expr();
            System.out.println(parseTree.toStringTree(parser));

        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I have the grammar from this site:
https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/python3

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

Your input file consists of two statements and you are parsing the file as if it was an expression (with line `ParseTree parseTree = parser.expr();`; rule `expr` from Python 3 grammar).

This also exaplains the first error: an identificator `a` is accepted as a part of expression but `=` sign is not. That's because `=` is a part of assignment statement.

### Solution

Parse the input using another grammar rule for example `file_input` rule which will accept many statements. Change the abovementioned line to `ParseTree parseTree = parser.file_input();`.

Comment: Thank you it's working! I tried to translate AST but all of my ideas were wrong. I haven't found the answer in ANTLR book yet. Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: @Daloteon what do you mean by translating AST? Translating to what?

Comment: I want to translate Python code to Java code. I have AST and I don't know what next. I tried to use this tree to generate code but it's not working.

Comment: @Daloteon look at this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40402039/migration-tool-for-antlr-grammar/40577702#40577702). Maybe it will be of any help for you.

Comment: Sorry for my long absence. It's working ! :) But I have another problem. I don't know which method from Python3BaseListener I must override to translate print() to System.out.println() and how to translate ':' to '{ '.
Link to files : [link](https://github.com/Daloteon/ANTLR)